# CSS sticky footer | Footer without a fixed height

Tags: css, sticky-footer

I have implemented the sticky footer many times from http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/. The only problem is that the footer has a fixed height. Is there a pure CSS solution to allow the footer to grow based on the content inside?

A JS solution wouldn't be bad, but CSS would be best.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Updated Answer*

The original answer is over five years old, and fails in that the padding is not updated in the event the footer height is increased, or decreased. You could bind to the *resize* event of the window, and call this on every fire, but that would be a bit excessive.

I would instead encourage you to bind to the `window.onresize` event, but *throttle* the logic such that we aren't computing styles, thrashing the DOM, and causing layouts **dozens of times per second**:

```js
(function () {

    "use strict";

    var body = document.querySelector( "body" );
    var footer = document.querySelector( "footer" );

    window.addEventListener(
        // Throttle logic: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/7b0neb6p/
        "resize", throttle( adjustContainerPadding(), 500 )
    );

    function adjustContainerPadding () {
        body.style.paddingBottom = window.getComputedStyle( footer ).height;
        return adjustContainerPadding;
    }

}());
```

When the page loads, we immediately fire the `adjustContainerPadding` method. This method sets the `paddingBottom` of the body to match the *computed height* of the `footer`. Note here that the `window.getComputedStyle` method requires IE9 or greater.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/7b0neb6p/

---

*Original Answer*

I would encourage you (for simplicity) to just use the cssstickyfooter code, and set the css values via javascript (jQuery code follows).

```
$(function(){
  var footerHeight = $("#footer").height();
  $("#main").css("padding-bottom", footerHeight);
  $("#footer").css("margin-top", -footerHeight);
});
```

*code is untested, but should work just fine*

No matter how much content you have in your footer, this will automatically reset the CSS values for you.

Comment: I feel this is the best solution so far. Even though it's using JS, I can set the footer to a large height in the css if JS is turned off. One thing is to change the last footerHeight to -footerHeight. It needs to be the negative value of the footer height. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Tom Glad I could be of assistance!

Comment: There is a much easier way of doing this, look at my answer below **NO FIXED HEIGHT, JAVASCRIPT OR TABLES**

Answer (score 5):

I really don't know why everyone is not using this technique. It's so easy

**NO FIXED HEIGHT, JAVASCRIPT OR TABLES**

Expands when more content, and when there isn't it sticks to bottom

```css
*{
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}
html, body{
  height: 100%; 
}
body{
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
}
.content{
  flex: 1;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    Header
  </header>
  
  <div class='content'>
    This is the page content
    <br>
    PS. Don't forget the margin: 0 and padding: 0 to avoid scrollbars (this can be also put into the   body css)
  </div>
  
  <footer>
    Footer
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Very easy and straightforward. It is also very elegant, because it doesn't use fixed height for the footer. Have you tested it with mobile devices?

Comment: @cezar works completely fine with updated mobile browsers.

Comment: Because I need it to always be sticky...

Answer (score 2):

**DISPLAY TABLE = NO JS and NO fixed height!**

Works in modern browsers ( IE 8 + ) - I tested it in several browser and it all seemed to work well.

I discovered this solution because I needed a sticky footer without fixed height and without JS. Code is below.

**Explanation:** Basically you have a container div with 2 child elements: a wrapper and a footer. Put everything you need on the page ( exept the footer ) in the wrapper. The container is set to `display: table;` The wrapper is set to `display: table-row;` If you set the html, body and wrapper to `height: 100%`, the footer will stick to the bottom.

The footer is set to `display: table;` as well. This is necessary, to get the margin of child elements. You could also set the footer to `display: table-row;` This will not allow you to set `margin-top` on the footer. You need to get creative with more nested elements in that case.

**The solution:** https://jsfiddle.net/0pzy0Ld1/15/

**And with more content:** http://jantimon.nl/playground/footer_table.html

```css
/* THIS IS THE MAGIC */

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body,
#container,
#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}
#container,
#wrapper,
#footer {
  width: 100%;
}
#container,
#footer {
  display: table;
}
#wrapper {
  display: table-row;
}
/* THIS IS JUST DECORATIVE STYLING */

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#header,
#footer {
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
#header {
  padding: 1em;
}
#content {
  background: orange;
  padding: 1em;
}
#footer {
  margin-top: 1em; /* only possible if footer has display: table !*/
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
      HEADER
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      CONTENT
      <br>
      <br>some more content
      <br>
      <br>even more content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <p>
      FOOTER
    </p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>
      MORE FOOTER
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following method is extremely simple and ensures that your footer adapts as your window resizes.

Inspiration from https://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/ and http://blog.mojotech.com/responsive-dynamic-height-sticky-footers/

CSS

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

JS

```
function positionFooter() {
  $("main").css("padding-bottom", $("footer").height());
}

// Initally position footer
positionFooter();

// Reposition footer on resize
$(window).resize(function() {
  positionFooter();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that it works on all browsers but try:

`#footer { position:absolute; top:100%; width:100%; }`

Answer (score 0):

check it out, it will be useful for you

```
var margin;
$(function(){
    var pageHeight = $('#pageKeeper').height();
    var clientHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;
```

`if (clientHeight > pageHeight) {
    margin = clientHeight - pageHeight;
    if (margin <= 120) {
        $('#footer').css('top', pageHeight + 30)
    }
    else {
        $('#footer').css('top', clientHeight - 90)
    }
}
else {
    margin = pageHeight - clientHeight;
    $('#footer').css('top', pageHeight + 30)
}
$('#footer').show()`

})